# Passing dynamic query strings in the endpoint for the callout

Tags: integration, string.format

We have been making an call out to an endpoint which till now was just accepting comma separated strings(two values) like /callme?ids='abc,xyz'.I implemented that as shown below and it worked fine:

```
private static final String ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE = '/callme?ids={0},{1}';
public Map<String,String> getsomething(List<String> Codes) {

   String endpointURL = String.format(ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE,Codes)}
```

Codes is a list of string that we pass.Now the requirement has changed and we can pass any number of string in the url to make a callout like /callme?ids='abc,xyz,pqy,jkl..'based on dynamic values of Codes.
How should we achieve this?Any immediate help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the String.join method ...

```
private static final String ENDOINT_TEMPLATE = '/callme?ids=';

public Map<String,String> getSomething(String[] Codes) {
    String endPointURL = ENDPOINT_TEMPLATE + String.join(Codes,',');
}
```